# Where CookieJar persists cookies?

Tags: go, session-cookies

The CookieJar seems to persist cookies somewhere not in memory but I couldn't find these details on documentation. So where CookieJar persists cookies? Is there a way to change where the cookies are persisted?

PS: Reason for the question is that cookies seems to survive after program is restarted.

Comment: Any explanation why the down vote?

Comment: The down vote tip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Package cookiejar](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/)
>
> ```
> import "net/http/cookiejar"
> ```
>
> Package cookiejar implements an in-memory RFC 6265-compliant
>   http.CookieJar.
>
> [jar.go](http://golang.org/src/net/http/cookiejar/jar.go)

Comment: And I can confirm that is does **not** persist cookies. But if someone has a good idea of how to do it: Contact me or Nigel.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation from `net/http/cookiejar` stores cookies in memory.

If you want a more persistent form of storage, you can do so by providing your own implementation of the `http.CookieJar` interface.